# Why does SWFObject work in chrome yet not IE/FF? (example included)

Tags: javascript, flash, browser, embed, swfobject

Am I using the code improperly or is there a flaw in SWFObject? If you go to the URL below you can see that it the flash file (an MP3 player) shows up perfectly fine in Chrome. However, in both Firefox and IE8 it loads a blank white box. If you mouse over the box the pointer changes to a hand as if its registering the buttons, just not actually displaying them.

Link: http://www.pulseblend.com/genres

(MP3 player should be displaying in the right-hand empty column)

Answer (score 1):

I get the player (flash) in Firefox 3.6.10. Chrome has a built-in flash plugin. IE and Firefox haven't. Get Flash Player from http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: I have Firefox 3.6.10 installed with flash 10.1.85.3. As I said in the post the actual file loads because I can mouse over where the buttons are. It's just invisible.

Comment: Strangely enough it works on my laptop just fine with the same version of FF and flash...

Comment: Try wrapping the `swfobject.embedSWF` code in an self-invoking function like `(function(){var flashvars = {};/*...*/swfobject.embedSWF(/*...*/)})()`.